# Calculating Pythagorean lengths using a Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am attempting to port the following Haskell code into Python and I am being greeted with an 'Invalid Syntax' response.

```
let rightTriangles' = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a+b+c == 24]
```

My unsuccessful attempt is below:

```
[(i,j,k) for i in range(1,11) for j in range(1,i+1) for k in range(1,j+1) if i**2 + j**2 == k**2 i + j + k == 24]
```

Python 3.4.4

Comment: What are `a, b, and c` supposed to be?

Comment: `i, j and k` probably?

Comment: You'd have to have some basic idea of how to write python, before actually writing python... For example, that is _not_ how you invoke `range`...

Comment: There's something missing between `k**2 i` at the end of your comprehension

Comment: It seems you are not ready to golf yet.

Comment: COLDSPEED: Oh, I do. A minor typing error is what you noticed.

Comment: I don't think the last constraint (24) signifies anything so I closed this. If that's not the case, feel free to reopen.

Comment: @ayhan 24 is the area of the triangle.

Comment: @CaitlinG A pythagorean triangle with sides `i, j, k` has the area `i*j/2` (given `k` is the hypotenuse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
>>> [
...    (i, j, k) 
...    for i in range(1, 11) 
...        for j in range(i, 11)      # j >= i
...            for k in range(j, 11)  # k >= j 
...                if i**2 + j**2 == k**2 and i + j + k == 24
... ]
[(6, 8, 10)]
```

Note that you need a comma in the range notation, an `and` between the conditions, and (judging from the first condition) `k` should be the biggest of the three, so you'd rather choose the ranges in a way that `i <= j <= k`.

`i < j < k` would save you some unnecessary iterations, since we know the hypotenuse is strictly longer than the legs that there are no Pythagorean triangles with equal legs.

Comment: Big fan of your answers. Keep em coming.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Honored!! :) or is that sarkasm? >:(

Comment: Nope, it's not :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ :D THX, also for the edit. makes it more readable indeed. Hmm... I answered this a minute too early however...